# Get a node form currenPage in CQ5

Tags: aem, jcr

I have a component that needs to fetch properties from another component on the same page.

Is there a way to get a component's `NODE` object from `currentPage` ?

I have the name of the node I need to fetch available in the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the node you need is in `Page/jcr:content/yournode`:

the `Page` object has a method `getContentResource()` which returns you the `jcr:content` resource node by default. You can also use `page.getContentResource("yournode")` to get a specific node below `jcr:content`.

If your node, for some reason is sibling to `jcr:content` (it shouldn't btw), you can your iterate the children of a resource using `resource.listChildren()`.

Remember, this is all Sling API, so you are managing resources, not nodes. You can get a JCR Node from a resource using `resource.adaptTo(Node.class)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually every Page class has a method for retrieving nodes within `jcr:content` that’s a little cleaner:

```
Node node = CurrentPage.getContentResource("COMPONENTNAME").adaptTo(Node.class);
```

Developers should check for a resource's existence before adapting it to a Node.

Now that we have a node, we can extract properties from that node.

```
String title = node.getProperty("jcr:title").getString();
```

This way you can fetch any properties of a component.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that this can be solved in more clean way by delegating request to a servlet provided the problem being solved requires separation of concerns -  separate the view from the controller logic.
[LINK EXPLAINING IN DETAIL HOW VALIDATION IS DONE USING SLING SERVLETS](http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2012/04/complex_cq5_dialog_validation.html)

Adds validator to a form using below logic that calls the sling servlet hosted

```
  var url = CQ.HTTP.addParameter(dialog.path + '.validator.json', 'value', value);
  var result = CQ.HTTP.eval(url);

 and in the servlet we access the node and its parents using below logic
   final Node currentNode = request.getResource().adaptTo(Node.class);
   try {
        final Node par = currentNode.getParent();

        final NodeIterator nodes = par.getNodes();

        // get all form names for the current paragraph system
        while (nodes.hasNext()) { //and the business logic
```

- See more at: http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2012/04/complex_cq5_dialog_validation.html#sthash.wey3cwdI.dpuf

Comment: PLEASE UPVOTE THE SOLUTION IF YOU FIND THIS HELPFUL